# How to initiate Function when Anchor tag is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
(function start (){

  $('.bar').each(function(i){  
    var $bar = $(this);
    $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
    setTimeout(function(){
      $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));      
    }, i*100);
  });

$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) +'%');
        }
    });
});

}, 500)
```

Im trying to find a way of triggering this when an anchor tag is reached on my page. All information is sectioned off into one page and this graph function animates. The problem is it is located further down my page on an #skills anchor and i want the animation/function triggered when that anchor is reached/seen.

Any thoughts? New to Js/JQ.

Thanks for your help.

```
<div class="bar cf" data-percent="100%"><span class="jacklabel"></span><span class="new_labels">SEO</span></div></div>
```

And the rest is CSS for the graph bars etc.

```
@mixin transition($transition-property, $transition-time, $method) {
    -webkit-transition: $transition-property $transition-time $method;
    -moz-transition: $transition-property $transition-time $method;
    -ms-transition: $transition-property $transition-time $method;
    -o-transition: $transition-property $transition-time $method;
    transition: $transition-property $transition-time $method;
}




.jackwrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bar: nth-child(3n+3) {  
  color: #ccc;
}
 .bar {
    padding-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background:#5b83d5;
    width: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: #FFF;
     transition:width 2s, background .2s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
     &:nth-of-type(2n) {
        background:lighten(#dadada , 10% );
     }

     .label {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    width: 8em;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
         &.light {
        background:lighten(#3d3d3d , 10% );
     }

}
 }
 .count {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.25em;
    top: 0.75em;
    padding: 0.15em;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: $fontSans;
    padding-top: 0px;
 }
.new_labels {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#keep-it-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a demo (jsfiddle) for what you are talking about? and is your question how can you trigger a certain function when a specific anchor tag is reached via scrolling down the page?

Comment: Thats exactly what i mean. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/127/

its just a general example that you can apply to your code (since i dont have access to your full code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scollH = 0;
    var aH = $('.special').position().top;
    console.log(aH);
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        scrollH = $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log(scrollH);
        if (scrollH > aH) {
            alert('i hit/am past the special anchor tag');
        }
    });
});

<div class="content">Other content above special anchor</div>
<a href="#" class="special">This is my Special Anchor Tag</a>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: That's right. That brings up an alert. So am i able to replace with my own function? Thanks for your help!!